# Accurev Install OSX

Tags: macos, accurev

I am getting the following error message when I try to install Accurev on my Mac OS X:

> AccurevClientInstall us damaged and can't be opened.

This happens no matter what version I try to install.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Answer here. There's a setting in the System Preferences.

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58050/damaged-and-cant-be-open-app-error-message

Comment: What version of OSx are you using?

Comment: 10.9.1. As above, I solved it using the link. This forum wouldn't take my answer as an 'answer' so it set it as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OSX Gatekeeper is attempting to protect you from malware and is set to report an error for third party software. Please see the following for a full explanation on this feature:

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5290